# Search by term giving empty result using elastica

Tags: php, search, elasticsearch, elastica

Using **Elastica - Elasticsearch PHP Client.** There are so many fields but I want to search in "Screen_name" field. What I have to do for it. I used term but without success. Result is empty array
Here is the code.

```
// Load index (database)
$elasticaIndex = $elasticaClient->getIndex('twitter_json');

//Load type (table)
$elasticaType = $elasticaIndex->getType('tweet_json');


$elasticaFilterScreenName   = new \Elastica\Filter\Term();    
$elasticaFilterScreenName->setTerm('screen_name', 'sohail'); 

//Search on the index.
$elasticaResultSet  = $elasticaIndex->search($elasticaFilterScreenName);

var_dump($elasticaResultSet); exit;
$elasticaResults    = $elasticaResultSet->getResults();
$totalResults       = $elasticaResultSet->getTotalHits();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say without knowing your mapping, but there is a good chance the document property "screen_name" does not contain the term "sohail".

Try using a Match query or a Query_String.

"Term" has special meaning in ElasticSearch.  A Term is the base, atomic unit of an index.  Terms are generated after your text is run through an analyzer.  If "screen_name" has an analyzer associated with the index, "sohail" is being modified in some capacity before being saved into the index.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I add an array of data and elasticsearch map it automatically. I just want to search in **screen_name** field. with term or any other method.

Comment: If you didn't specify an analyzer, ES will automatically use the [Standard Analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/standard-analyzer.html).  Try using a Match query, that will probably work for you.

Comment: Now I am trying this but empty result again.
`$elasticaQueryMatch = new Elastica\Query\Match();
$elasticaQueryMatch->setField('screen_name', 'sohail');

//Search on the index.
$elasticaResultSet  = $elasticaIndex->search($elasticaQueryMatch);

var_dump($elasticaResultSet); exit;`

Comment: I'm not familiar with Elastica, sorry.  Try using raw CURL commands from a command-line to make sure your queries work (or use a plugin like Inquisitor or Head), then translate it to Elastica.

Comment: Thanks it working now. actually I don't know why **screen_name** is not searchable. But when I search in **text** field it works